# Pyspark: long filter chaining makes the driver hang

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose we have a list of predicates that we would like to construct a chain of filters. When the list of predicates exceeds ~20, the driver just hangs and a job never shows up in the spark ui.

For example:

```
df = spark.table('test.test')

for predicate in predicates_list:
    positive_case = df.filter(predicate)
    negative_case = df.filter(~predicate)
    #some changes are made to negative and positive case
    df = positive_case.union(negative_case)

df.show()
```

The only alternative I can think of is to write all of it in a python function and jump into rdd land. However, this seems like a very hacky solution to a seemingly trivial problem.

Comment: do I understand correctly - you're just trying to add column with different values for positive and negative cases?

Comment: moreover you're overwriting this column value's ~20 times (depends how many predicates you have)?

Comment: @V.G. I made changes to make the question clearer. The main point is that many filters makes the driver hang, not what I do with a column.

Comment: Haha, Looks your code do nothing... split and then union..., @icarus, you better attach **df.printSchema()** and **table size** and you computer memory available size.

Comment: it would be useful to see reproducable example. I've seen quite a large queries (filter predicates) but never experience driver hang cause of that.

Comment: It might be worth trying to get all of your predicates into a single filter. It's only a theory right now, but it seems like this would equate to 3 * number_of_predicates operations on the dataframe in sequence. If you can get them into one `filter` it might help.

Comment: Assuming your predicates are strings: `full_predicate_string = ' and '.join(['({0} or not ({0}))'.format(predicate) for predicate in predicates])` No guarantees, but it might be worth a try to see if it helps.

Comment: @V.G. Yes, you understand correctly. I am trying to add different values for positive and negative cases.